# Why does Lasso give piecewise linear solutions?

Tags: lasso

I've seen results stating that the solution path to 
$$\hat{\beta} = \underset{\beta}{\text{argmin}} ||Y - X\beta||_2^2 + \lambda ||\beta||_1$$
is piecewise linear, in the sense that the solution $\hat{\beta}(\lambda)$ is piecewise linear as a function of $\lambda$. I was wondering if anyone had any intuitive explanations for this, in the same way that there is an intuitive geometric explanation for why Lasso solutions tend to be sparse. I imagine it has to do with the $\ell^1$ penalty being linear in each $|\beta_i|$, but I can't seem to see why that would do it.

Comment: I think essentially the same "sphere and diamond" picture works, but you have to think about it a bit more dynamically. You want to track the point of tangency of the sphere centered around the linear regression solution (a level curve of the MSE), and the L1 ball centered at the origin (the diamond). As the L1 ball shrinks, the point of tangency moves along a line, the ray centered at the LR solution and passing through the point of intersection with one of the faces of a large diamond just not containing the regression solution...

Comment: I'd take some work to make this a rigorous geometric argument, but I think it could be done.

Comment: Tibshirani gives some geometric intuition of this property in Section 3.6 of these [lecture notes](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/statml/lectures/sparsity.pdf).

Comment: @MatthewDrury I independently rediscovered your same picture and drew it in my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Lasso Solution Path]

Here the contour lines of the MSE are in blue, and the contour lines of the $\ell_1$ norm are in purple.

A lasso $\hat{\beta}_\lambda$ which isn't on an axis must be at a point of tangency between the $\ell_1$ ball and the MSE contour.

Why?

Assume to the contrary that $\beta$ is optimal and lies at a point where the purple and blue curves are transverse.  Then staying on an MSE contour we would be able to cross $\ell_1$ contours.  So we could keep $MSE$ constant while decreasing $\ell_1$.

Now consider the geometry of the situation.  If we have the MLE $\hat{\beta}_0$ (at the center of all of the ellipses) and some other $\hat{\beta}_{\lambda_1}$ we get a line.  The contour lines of the MSE are all dilations of each other from $\hat{\beta}_0$, and the purple tangent lines come along for the ride!  So we can be sure that all of the $\hat{\beta}_{\lambda}$ lie on the line segment connecting $\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat{\beta}_{\lambda_1}$ until we get to a coordinate axis.

The same argument works fine in higher dimensions as well!  You just get similar ellipsoids with tangent hyperplanes.

Comment: p.s.  I actually drew this picture to help explain Lasso for some course notes and noticed the piecewise linear solution path.  I got excited because I had never heard this observation before, googled to see if it had been noted, and found this question (as well as the original papers where it was observed).